# Combining the results of multiple observables

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, observable, reactive-programming

I'm trying to achieve something like this: 
- Make two different API calls and combine the results into a list. The result for each call is a HashMap and I have a function to convert it to a list. What I'm trying to do now is to combine the lists into one but I'm having difficulty.

This is what my Retrofit service looks like:

```
@GET("data/price?fsym=ETH")
fun getETHRates(@Query("tsyms") tsyms : String) : Single<HashMap<String, Double>>

@GET("data/price?fsym=BTC")
fun getBTCRates(@Query("tsyms") tsyms: String) : Single<HashMap<String, Double>>
```

I've been able to make the calls separately and transform the result into a list(please correct me if this can be done better) like this:

```
val btcRates: Single<List<Currency>> = cryptoApi.getBTCRates(countries)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .flatMap { result: HashMap<String, Double> ->
            return@flatMap Single.just(createCurrencyObjects("BTC", result))
        }

val ethRates: Single<List<Currency>> = cryptoApi.getETHRates(countries)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .flatMap { result: HashMap<String, Double> ->
            return@flatMap Single.just(createCurrencyObjects("ETH", result))
        }
```

This is the function that transforms the result into a list:

```
fun createCurrencyObjects(from: String, map: HashMap<String, Double>): List<Currency> {
    val list = ArrayList<Currency>(0)

    for (key in map.keys) {
        val amount: Double? = map.get(key)
        list.add(Currency(0, from, key, amount!!))
    }

    return list;
}
```

What I want to do now is combine the lists from both calls and then save it into a database. How do I do this combination with RxJava?

I've tried something like this but I keep getting error messages:

```
val apiCall: Disposable = Observable.concat(ethRates, btcRates)
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnNext { values: List<Currency> ->
            run {
                App.database?.currencyDao()?.insertAllCurrencies(values)
            }
        }.doOnError { e -> e.printStackTrace() }
        .subscribe();
```

Comment: Observable.zip() should do the trick.

Comment: or Observable.combineLatest();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `zip` operator you can combine the result of both `Single` and apply a transforming function that returns a list

```
Single.zip(
            rates1,
            rates2,
            BiFunction<List<Currency>, List<Currency>, List<Currency>> { x, y ->
                // return your list
            }
    ).doOnSuccess { list -> // save your data }
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer of gyosida is correct. Here is another example showing a generic use of Zip:

```
    val single1 = Single.just(mutableListOf("one", "two", "three"))
    val single2 = Single.just(mutableListOf("four", "five", "six"))

    val single = Single.zip(single1, single2, BiFunction {
        a: MutableList<String>, b: MutableList<String> ->
            a.addAll(b)
            return@BiFunction a
    })
```

Happy coding!